# Gitlab CI - Trigger daily pipeline only if new chanes have been commited

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

The company I work for has a self hosted Gitlab CE server `v13.2.1`.

For a specific project I've setup the CI jobs to build according to the following workflow :

- If a commit has been pushed to the main branch
- If a merge request has been created
- If a tag has been pushed
- Every day at midnight to build the main branch (using scheduled pipelines)

Everything works fine. The only thing I would like to improve is that the nightly builds are performed even if the main branch has not been modified (no new commit).

I had a look to the Gitlab documentation to change my `workflow:` rules in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file but I didn't find anything relevant.

The gitlab runner is installed in a VM and is setup as a shell executor. I was thinking of creating in the home directory a file to store the last commit ID. I'm not a big fan of that solution, because :

1. it's a ugly fix.
2. The pipeline will be triggered by Gitlab even if it does nothing. This will pollute the pipeline list.

Is there any way to setup the `workflow:` section to perform this so the pipeline list won't contain unnecessary pipeline ?